# Prolog: Finding the cheapest combination of N facts

Tags: prolog

For the following facts:

```
% item (number, price)
item(1, 40);
item(2, 50);
item(3, 45);
item(4, 65);
item(5, 15);
```

How can I determine what is the cheapest combination of N element in `Prolog`?

for example

```
?- cheapestCombination(3, [item(1, 40), item(2, 50), item(3, 45), item(4, 65), item(5, 15)], L).

L = [item(1,40), item(3,45), item(5,15)].
```

For now I can form a list of list of N combinations with the following code:

```
combination(0, _, []) :- 
    !.
combination(N, L, [V|R]) :-
    N > 0,
    NN is N - 1,
    unknown(V, L, Rem),
    combination(NN, Rem, R).

unknown(X,[X|L],L).
unknown(X,[_|L],R) :- 
    unknown(X,L,R).
```

But I don't know how to manipulate this list of list so that I can sum the list inside the list of list, and extract the minimum of the list of list.

Comment: I think you can do something like this: ```?- sort(2, =<, [item(1,40), item(2,50), item(3,45), item(4,65), item(5,15)], S), length(C,3), preffix(C,S).``` You only need to generalize this query, transforming it into a rule.

Comment: Can an item be used more than once? Based on your example result the answer appears to be no. You should state that in the question.